How to merge large CSV files using Python?
I have a dataset of many large CSV files (total volume is 30GB). Every file gives specific type  information about people. But all files have a column named 'ID', which describes about whom is the given info. How can I merge all CSV files by the column 'ID', so in the fully merged file I will have the full info about every ID?
I have 16GB of RAM and 64 GB of swap memory and even that is not enough for merging files with pandas or polars.

If you're running out of memory, the easiest solution is to spill to disk. I'd merge the data into an SQLite database first (e.g. into a simple EAV table like (id, column, value)). It's easy to read from there by subsequent tools.

maybe you should do it without pandas or polars but use use standard module csv to read row by row and write it to new file (with name based on ID) - this way you will have one row in memory. Eventually you can try to use df.read_csv(..., chunksize=...) to read data in small parts and pd.to_csv(..., mode='a') to append to existing file

Can you provide the column names and the values of few rows? Also: something may to be wrong about the way i.e. 'polars'  converts CSVs to data frames. By that I mean data types in the columns. Check for things preventing polars getting numerical values instead of strings

it would be helpful to know how man unique ID's you have, how many columns you have across the files for each ID.

Reevaluate your approach. You already have all the info about a specific ID just spread in bunch of CSV files and a less than acceptable way o extracting it.
No matter which approach you take in the end, I suggest converting individual CSVs to parquet:
import glob
import polars as pl

for csv_fn in glob.glob("../*tsv"):
    print(csv_fn)
    df = pl.read_csv(csv_fn, separator="\t").sort("id")
    df.write_parquet(csv_fn.replace('tsv', "parquet"), compression="zstd", compression_level=9)

To get a full info about a specific id you may use duckdb:
 SELECT * FROM read_parquet("*.parquet", union_by_name=true) WHERE ID='foobar_123';

PS
If you really want to join all the CSVs (now parquets) in a giant data frame using less resources/RAM you can:

make sure conversion of all suitable values to numerical values works. So no 5 days or 123456$
encode the obvious values: female == F or even: 0 = unknown, 1 = female, 2 = male. Same thing for the departments, cities, etc,
when merging two data frames use polars merge_sorted.


I have not experience in working with such amounts of data but probably you could try the following: divide each of your files into some k equal parts (for example you could try k=10). Then, merge the first parts of all of your files by ID, after which merge all the second parts of your files and so on.
For example if you have 3 files a, b, c, then after dividing each one you will get lists of files
[a_0, ..., a_{k-1}]
[b_0, ..., b_{k-1}]
[c_0, ..., c_{k-1}]

Then, after merging a_i, b_i, c_i for each i you will end up with k files each of which is 30/k=3GB and there should be enough room in your RAM for this amount.
Only make sure to divide your files so that the i-th parts of your files (a_i, b_i, c_i) contain records with the same IDs. For this you could simply sort each file by IDs before dividing the files.

Since the dataset is too large for your RAM (and probably even your combined memory), you'll need Dask that break the task into chunks:
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSVs as Dask DataFrames (lazy loading, no data in memory yet)
df1 = dd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = dd.read_csv('file2.csv')
# ... more files

# Merge on 'ID' column
merged_df = dd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='outer')

# Compute to trigger execution and save the result
merged_df.to_csv('merged_data.csv', index=False)  # Save as a single CSV

